# Import mails into an account with IMAP

Tags: .net, exchange-server, imap, hotmail

I know I can download mails from an account with IMAP. But is it possible to import (or create) mails into an account with IMAP? I specifically would like to import messages into a hotmail account.

Apparently I can't do that with the official LiveSDK API, but can I do it directly with IMAP?

And if it is not possible, is there any other way to achieve this? (I don't need a tool or an existing application, I would like to do this from my own .NET app.)

UPDATE: I found out that Hotmail does not support the IMAP protocol. But it does support Exchange Server and DeltaSync. Is it possible to import mails with any of them? Could you provide some useful links with proper information? (i couldn't find any yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, DeltaSync is closed-source, undocumented and **SSL-encrypted**.
There are no (reasonably complete) implementations of it in .NET, and neither will you be able to reverse-engineer it in a reasonable amount of time. 

If you try, you need **oSpy** to view the sent and recieved packets/XML in clear text. However, oSpy only works on 32-bit programs.

Additionally, DeltaSync is a protocol for sending and receiving emails via **XMLhttpRequest**.
While this allows reading and thus exporting of a mailbox, it is unlikely that it also supports import.

What you can do is downloading the emails using IMAP, and sending them using a fake sender (original sender) to the desired  mailbox. 
**That will change all dates**, however, and you shouldn't let the **CC's and BCC's** in when doing the send, which means you loose all the email addresses contained in CC and BCC fields, unless you include them on top of the message as text...

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Do you happen to have any information about the Exchange ActiveSync protocol? (Which is also supported by Hotmail according to Wikipedia. Some sources even state that Hotmail supports Exchange Server, which I do not even understand. Exchange Server is a standalone server-side product, isn't it? So what's the connection between Hotmail and Exchange Server?)

Comment: @Mark: Can't say. Before HotMail.com was acquired by Microsoft, everything ran on FreeBSD so there was never and could never ever be any connection between HotMail.com and ExchangeServer. Microsoft CLAIMS they have since moved the system over to Windows server, so they might have used Exchange as a mailserver backend. However, I think this is highly unlikely, because Exchange simply can't handle this amount of accounts with this kind of load, and neither can the Windows server IP stack.

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime I looked at the documentation of the Exchange ActiveSync protocol, and it seems that it is not possible to import mails into an account with it either. The interesting thing is, that you CAN import mails with trueswitch (https://secure5.trueswitch.com/hotmail/) and with the Windows Live Mail client, but I can't figure out how they are doing it. Maybe both use the DeltaSync protocol.

Comment: @Mark: Then you should use oSpy on trueswitch :)

Comment: TrueSwitch is a server-side application with a web client, I can not spy that.